# Why does Ember complain when pushing an object onto an Ember array?

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

I am using **Ember RC6.1** with **[Ember Model](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model)**. When I set the `adapter` property of a model class to an instance of Ember Model's `RESTAdpater` class and perform a `findAll`, an assertion is thrown for each object that is added to the resulting Ember array. The stack trace shows that the object is pushed onto the array, inserted, and then replaced. I am not sure why the latter (replacing) occurs. This might be the result of an implicit sort.

For each push, an assertion is thrown stating that the `content` property of an instance of `RecordArray` (which inherits from `ArrayProxy`) should be set before modifying it.

```
Assertion failed: The content property of Ember.RecordArray should be set before modifying it
```

The resulting array behaves normally, but I am wondering if this is a bug in Ember Model or Ember itself. I assume that my code is not responsible for this bug as I do nothing out of the ordinary aside from fetching the data from an API as per documentation of Ember Model.

I have added the stack trace below.

```
(anonymous function) application.js:6108
Ember.assert application.js:5799
Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend._replace application.js:17977
Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend._insertAt application.js:17992
Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend.pushObject application.js:18036
superWrapper application.js:6826
Ember.Model.reopenClass.addToRecordArrays application.js:5251
(anonymous function) application.js:5242
sendEvent application.js:7843
Ember.Evented.Ember.Mixin.create.trigger application.js:16867
Ember.Model.Ember.Object.extend.load application.js:4792
Ember.Model.reopenClass.findFromCacheOrLoad application.js:5280
(anonymous function) application.js:4453
Ember.RecordArray.Ember.ArrayProxy.extend.materializeData application.js:4452
Ember.RecordArray.Ember.ArrayProxy.extend.load application.js:4435
Ember.RESTAdapter.Ember.Adapter.extend.didFindAll application.js:5585
(anonymous function) application.js:5576
invokeCallback application.js:12843
(anonymous function) application.js:12886
EventTarget.trigger application.js:12674
(anonymous function) application.js:12941
DeferredActionQueues.flush application.js:10648
Backburner.end application.js:10338
Backburner.run application.js:10377
Ember.run application.js:10859
settings.success application.js:5697
fire application.js:38117
self.fireWith application.js:38228
done application.js:45154
callback
```

**UPDATE: The call to `pushObject` is performed by Ember Model. I have added the implementation of `addToRecordArrays`, the method in which the record is added to the instance of `RecordArray`.**

```
addToRecordArrays: function(record) {
  if (this._findAllRecordArray) {
    this._findAllRecordArray.pushObject(record);
  }
  if (this.recordArrays) {
    this.recordArrays.forEach(function(recordArray) {
      recordArray.pushObject(record);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the code where you are trying to push into to the `RecordArray`?

Comment: Sure. However, it is important to know that this done by Ember Model.

Comment: Should this be flagged as an issue on the Ember-Model Github repo? I'm seeing this as well...

Comment: Submitted as an issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3122

Comment: I was a bit cautious with regards to submitting an issue as I couldn't find any reports of this issue. However, it is good to know that someone else can reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reverted the commit that introduced this issue.

Comment: After having looked at the [pull request](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/pull/198), the assertions and corresponding stack trace make sense.